# Code not executed in expected order?

Tags: java, android, thread-sleep

Can someone please explain to me why the code via the link below isn't getting executed as expected?  I think I'm ignorant to something about how threads execute but obviously I don't know what. any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Visually, I'm expecting it to show four Toasts in the following order:
 1. createToast("start of delayed RandomCue Method");
 2. createToast("start of delay");
 3. createToast("end of delay");
 4. createToast("end of delayed RandomCue Method");

However, the resulting order is:
 1. createToast("start of delayed RandomCue Method");
 2. createToast("end of delayed RandomCue Method");
 3. createToast("end of delay");
 4. createToast("start of delay");

My overall goal is to have a program that displays an image and changes ever 3 seconds.  The player can press a button and the image changes for 1.5 seconds.  Therefore, there are two methods, one to change picture using countdowntimer and another to change picture using onClick method corresponding to imagebutton.

The problem I'm running into is the code provided in the link (method called from within an onclick method) is supposed to change the image, set a bool value to false, wait 1.5 seconds, and then change the same bool value back to true.

While the bool value is true, the method that changes the pictures is supposed to be skipped but that's not the case and I don't know why but i think it's something to do with the code in the gists I created below.

So the issue I have is when the button is clicked, the image changes as expected but it sometimes changes again too quickly due to the first method not recognizing that the player responded and thus shouldn't change image yet.

Please let me know if any further details or anything is needed and thank you again for time and help!!

https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d32446ceb8c6d9626c68#file-easyfragment-java
https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d32446ceb8c6d9626c68

https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d0a0b124dfe17666be25#file-easyfragment-java
https://gist.github.com/cjayem13/d0a0b124dfe17666be25

```
 onclick(){
delayedRandomCue(final long a)
}
```